# Как выровнять lineEdit с маской в ячейке таблицы?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, inputmask, qstyleditemdelegate

Использую `QTableView`. Сделал маску ввода для колонки, но ширина `lineEdit` изменилась.

Это заметно, когда она начинает быть в фокусе при редактировании.

Как это пофиксить?

Код маски:

```
QWidget *EditMaskDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    auto * edit = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);
    if(auto * lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(edit))
    {
        lineEdit->setInputMask("0000-00-00");
        lineEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    }
    return edit;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже у разрабов баг, или какая-то хитрая логика с ограничением на ширину поля ввода с маской.

Вот так работает:

```
class EditMaskDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    EditMaskDelegate(QObject * parent = nullptr): QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        auto * edit = QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent,option,index);
        if(auto * lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(edit))
        {
            lineEdit->setInputMask("0000-00-00");
            lineEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);

            // Иначе, при использовании маски, максимальная ширина 
            // поля ввода устанавливается в 100px
            lineEdit->setMaximumWidth(100000);
        }
        return edit;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        if (edit) {
            // Сохраняем текущую геометрию
            QRect rect = editor->geometry();

            // Устанавливаем текущее значение в поле ввода
            edit->setText(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());

            // Переустанавливаем ширину виджета после сброса в 
            // предыдущей строке до 100px
            edit->setMinimumWidth(rect.width());

            // Если добавить эту строку, то ширина поля ввода
            // полностью соответствует ширине ячейки таблицы 
            // во всех диапазонах
            edit->setMaximumWidth(rect.width());
        }
    }

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        editor->setMinimumWidth(option.rect.width());
        editor->setMaximumWidth(option.rect.width());
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }
};
```

Comment: void EditMaskDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid() && editor) {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(editor, option, index);
    }
} Вроде все верно сделал, но не выходит.

Comment: Данные заполняются. Вот скрин - https://prnt.sc/KrCbLe5WEFin. LineEdit не по ширине ячейки.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ut1LXlgUE1gC Не вышло

Comment: ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, new EditMaskDelegate(this));

Comment: Попробовал сделать так - https://prnt.sc/R9O8DJ16fLOU, но безуспешно

Comment: @MuhamedAli похоже тут есть баг у разрабов. Все проверил и теперь правильный ответ выглядит так )

Comment: Да работает, спасибо большое. Единственное, когда ресайзишь колонку проблема остается. То есть, ячейка в фокусе и при изменении размера она не меняет ширину автоматически

Comment: @MuhamedAli при уменьшении колонки, видимо?

Comment: Когда увеличиваю и уменьшаю размер

Comment: @MuhamedAli при увеличении я не вижу никаких проблем

Comment: @MuhamedAli добавил еще одну строчку и теперь во всех диапазонах размер поля ввода соответствует размеру ячейки

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!

Comment: @MuhamedAli еще нашел косяк ) Добавил доп.код (метод updateEditorGeometry) теперь работает (тук-тук-тук) вроде бы во всех режимах нормально ))